# How to add an existing email account to outlook using c++

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi, outlook-2003

I need to write a small program that will be able to add existing email accounts to outlook so that we will be able to recieve email messages on a virtual machine. We are using outlook 2003 and outlook 2010 (A 2003 solution is more important though)

It is not possible to do by hand as it needs to be part of an automated test and setting them up manually all the time would not be feasable.

I have looked around on google and I can't seem to find any help in using the Extended MAPI so I thougt I would come here.

If anyone could help me out by then that would be great.

If you have an option using either vb script or c# that would also be useful.

Comment: I would try to prototype this in PowerShell then go for whatever language is most convenient.

Comment: I have tried looking at a few samples of sending emails etc... but couldnt actually find any for what I want and also I wasnt able to figure out any of the commands that I would need to get it working.

Powershell might be a good option. I will ask someone at work if they could give me a hand with that.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

What kind of account? 
POP3/SMTP accounts are not MAPI based and MS did not document the parts of the IOlkAccountManager interface responsible for creating new accounts.
For Exchange accounts, use IMsgServiceAdmin::CreateMsgService("MSEMS", ...) - MSDN has a few example of how to do that. For the PST accounts, the service name will be "MSPST MS" or "MSUPST MS".

Comment: We have a Microsoft Exchange Server that we use so it will be that. I'll have a look at MSDN for that function cheers.

Comment: It looks like that can only work with Outlook 2007/2010/2013. It HAS to work on 2003, but 2010 would be a great bonus though. Do you know of an equivalent for 2003?

Comment: If you use Extended MAPI to add and configure the MSEMS service, your code will work just fine in Outlook 2003. I don't think that functionality changed since Outlook 98.